# jTextField output value in array

Tags: java, arrays, textfield

I want to save the value out of a TextField in an Array. But i think i do something wrong, may someone be so nice and could take a look on my code sniplet ?

```
 //Array

Carl[0]=jNumberFieldAE.getInt();
Carl[1]=jNumberFieldIT.getInt();
Carl[2]=jNumberFieldWIG.getInt();
Carl[3]=jNumberFieldPol.getInt();
Carl[4]=jNumberFieldRel.getInt();
Carl[5]=jNumberFieldE.getInt();
Carl[6]=jNumberFieldDeutsch.getInt();
Carl[7]=jTextFieldName.getText();
```

Is .getText(); not right ?

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better answers sooner

Answer (score 0):

Array are fixed length, Size of array cannot be modified and cant have different type. Make it an arraylist and add dynamically.

```
List<String> ArrList= new ArrayList<String>()

name = jTextFieldName.getText();
text1= Integer.parseInt(jNumberFieldAE.getText());
...more

// Add to list
ArrList.add(name);
ArrList.add(text1);
```

If you still need array convert List to Array

```
String [] strArr = ArrList.toArray(new String[ArrList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

JTextField has String as value, so you must parse it to retreive your integer value. Try this code :

```
Carl[0]= Integer.parseInt(jNumberFieldAE.getText());
...
```

Comment: Yeah but i dont want to get Text out of a NumberfieldField, i want to get Text out of a TextField. I tryed your Version and no error comes up but it wont work.

Carl[7]= Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldName.getText());

i basicly just want to save the Text which is filled in a jTextField in an Array and give it out with an "output" button after i saved it with an "input" button